# How to return values created by trigger for JOOQ record store?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, jooq

since several weeks we use JOOQ as our main persistence framework instead of all those Spring Data JPA/Hibernate stuff. I'm really impressed !!!

For simple CRUD operations we use `record.store()` and this record is an `UpdatableRecordImpl` due to the underlying table contains an ID (column `id` with PostgreSQL type `serial`) Furthermore JOOQ is configured with `withReturnAllOnUpdatableRecord(true)` and our table contains a trigger to generate the value for the column `nummer`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."after_insert_angebot" () RETURNS trigger
VOLATILE
AS $body$
DECLARE
BEGIN
UPDATE kalkulation_angebot SET nummer = date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) || '-' || LPAD(NEW.id::text, 3, '0') WHERE id = NEW.id;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql

CREATE TRIGGER "after_insert_angebot"
  AFTER INSERT ON kalkulation_angebot
  FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE after_insert_angebot()
```

I expect, that after `record.store()` and due to `withReturnAllOnUpdatableRecord(true)` the record contains values for the id (generated by the column type) and nummer (generated by the trigger). But only the `id` is filled. I have to manually set the `nummer` by an extra query:

```
// jooq fetched the new values and the id is available
Integer angebotId = record.getId();

// ... but nummer is missing and has to set manually
angebot.setNummer(jooq.select(KALKULATION_ANGEBOT.NUMMER)
        .from(KALKULATION_ANGEBOT)
        .where(KALKULATION_ANGEBOT.ID.eq(record.getId()))
        .fetchSingleInto(String.class));
```

I assume, the error is within the trigger function ? How the trigger should be, in order to fulfill the promise of the documentation:

> The identity value is not the only value that is generated by default. Specifically, there may be triggers that are used for [...] Users who wish to also automatically fetch these values after all store(), insert(), or update() calls may do so by specifying the returnAllOnUpdatableRecord setting

Thanks in advance
Dominik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `withReturnAllOnUpdatableRecord(true)` produces an `INSERT .. RETURNING` or `UPDATE .. RETURNING` statement in jOOQ. Since you've defined an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, this does not help returning the values as you might have expected. Try it in vanilla PostgreSQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE kalkulation_angebot (
  id serial,
  nummer text
);

-- Your own TRIGGER below:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."after_insert_angebot" () RETURNS trigger
VOLATILE
AS $body$
BEGIN
  UPDATE kalkulation_angebot 
  SET nummer = date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) || '-' || LPAD(NEW.id::text, 3, '0')
  WHERE id = NEW.id;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER "after_insert_angebot"
  AFTER INSERT ON kalkulation_angebot
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE after_insert_angebot();

INSERT INTO kalkulation_angebot DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING *;
```

The output being:

```
|id         |nummer  |
|-----------|--------|
|1          |        |
```

How about you replace your trigger to what I would believe to be much more meaningful anyway:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."before_insert_angebot" () RETURNS trigger
VOLATILE
AS $body$
BEGIN
  NEW.nummer = date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) || '-' || LPAD(NEW.id::text, 3, '0');
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER "before_insert_angebot"
  BEFORE INSERT ON kalkulation_angebot
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE before_insert_angebot();

INSERT INTO kalkulation_angebot DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING *;
```

The output is now:

```
|id         |nummer  |
|-----------|--------|
|1          |2020-001|
```

Comment: Perfect, as I already suspected, the error was within the trigger/function... something we try to learn to use more and more. Thank you for this fast and proper answer.